# Grub Boot Loader Error Occured when Ubuntu and SlackWare is Installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, slack

I have a PC which has a pre-installed Ubuntu 18 OS. On the free partition I have installed Slackware 14.2 successfully.

After that I have decided to install GRUB, using the commands below:

```
chroot /mnt
lsblk
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
exit
reboot
```

Running grub-mkconfig has one error on the end.

```
grub-probe unknown filesystem
```

After rebooting I can successfully boot to Slackware but not to Ubuntu. Ubuntu shows an error below:

```
error file '/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic' not found error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Answer (score 0):

Grub2 is the default bootloader in Ubuntu. Grub2 has the advantage that it brings up a menu on booting and it is possible to use the menu to dual boot with Ubuntu and other operating systems. Replace Slackware's default LILO bootloader with grub2. There are a few tutorials describing various ways of installing grub2 in the Slackware documentation, depending on what hardware you are using.

Boot-Repair can solve the majority of bootsector/GRUB/MBR problems.

1. Download [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files).
2. Write it on a live USB stick using [UNetbootin](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/system/unetbootin/) USB creator application.
3. Insert the Boot Repair disk and reboot the computer.
4. Choose your language.
5. Connect to the internet if possible.
6. Click the *Recommended repair (repairs most frequent problems)* button.

   [image]
7. Reboot the computer.